# Sensible value for autovacuum_cost_delay

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, autovacuum

I'm running a data warehouse on an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance. Most of the heavy lifting is done during the night-batch, and very often we use a TRUNCATE-rebuild strategy, also for large tables (100M rows).

This seems to cause issues with autovacuum, between 2 and 4 the night batch 7 out of 10 of the TOP SQL statements are VACUUM ANALYZE statements for the large tables:
[image]
and they are hugging my RDS system
[image]
and dropping the Byte Balance to 0, after which the machine slows down enormously :
[image]

Obviously it would be wiser to postpone the VACUUM ANALYZE to a later timeframe, when the machine is almost idle.

After reading some documentation I can think of two strategies to get this done:

1. turn off Autovacuum for these large tables, and schedule a process that runs Vacuum later
2. set the `autovacuum_cost_delay` to a sensible value. since that would postpone the Vacuum processing in general (or maybe set it to a sensible value for just these tables).

However, what is a sensible value in this case? I read that the default is 2 milliseconds. How much larger is sensible 200ms? 10 seconds? 1 minute? 60 minutes?

I'm looking for a sensible value to start testing with or other advice that can help me.

NB. the machine is  2cpu, 16GB m6g.large and these are the current settings for the autovauccum related parameters:

[image]

**Extra info**
@jjanes yes, it barely touches a byte balance of 0, however, This is a careful balance I actually managed to achieve. I regularly encountered the situation that it took very long to recover from a situation that it dropped to 0 actually. Example
[image]

My machine then starts to build up read/write latency and DiskQueueDepth as well

Bulk loading at night is concerning many tables (currently ~900), which are all loaded/transformed through jobs between 23h and 6:30h, with the most busy time between 2h and 4h. Many tables are small, only a few are quite large.
[image]

@jjanes & @frank-heikens, which later version does make a difference?
here's two screenshots from the situation after before & after migration from 14 to 15:
Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

**Update** Implemented the suggestion of @Laurence Albe. Observations:

Byte Balance much better:
[image]

Database load much more even:
[image]

Comment: Your byte balance doesn't linger at 0.  As soon as it hits zero, it starts climbing steadily again.  At which point does the machine slow down and how long does it slow down for?  If the machine is trying to use more IO than it is allowed, that should only happen while the byte balance is zero, and from the chart that only happens for a very brief  period (one pixel)

Comment: When does the bulk load stop and the VACUUM start?  Is the bulk load all in one table or in many tables?  All in one transaction or in many transactions?

Comment: The VACUUM part doesn't make sense to me: TRUNCATE rebuilds the table and doesn't need VACUUM and inserting new data won't trigger a VACUUM either, only ANALYZE. What is missing in this picture?

Comment: @FrankHeikens inserts do cause vacuum in newer versions. (Intended to set hint bits and the visibility map.)

Comment: @jjanes I tried to add answers to your questions in an edit

Comment: @FrankHeikens I tried to add answers to your questions in an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable [`autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#RELOPTION-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-INSERT-THRESHOLD) for the tables in question:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz SET (
   autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold = -1,
   toast.autovacuum_vacuum_insert_threshold = -1
);
```

Then loading data will not trigger autovacuum. Make sure to trigger an explicit `VACUUM` on the table after the load is done and before you start querying the table.

Comment: This left me with an error: pyodbc.DataError: ('22023', '[22023] ERROR: value -1 out of bounds for option "autovacuum_vacuum_threshold"\nDETAIL: Valid values are between "0" and "2147483647".;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the wrong storage option.

Comment: Thanks for fixing. It seems to work now

Comment: Implemented. Results in Edit of question.

Answer (score 0):

The TOP SQL chart doesn't mean much.  All of the vacuum statements are near the top merely due to Timeout:VacuumDelay (assuming the color scheme is the same between the two panels.)  This doesn't show that vacuum is experiencing problems, nor that it is causing them. All that this shows is that the vacuum is trying to avoid causing problems, with unknown level of success. (A top SQL chart should arguably exclude this type of time from its sorting.)

Vacuum certainly can use a lot of IO, but we just don't have any evidence here that it is what is causing the problem.  It is perfectly plausible that it is the bulk loading itself which is depleting your IO. You say the IO balance only hits zero for a brief moment because you do a careful balancing act, but without knowing what that act is, it is hard to use it to attribute a cause.

You might want to set the autovacuum_cost_delay so that autovacuum by itself cannot deplete the IO balance faster than its recharge rate.  But we don't know what that recharge rate is, you have told us the machine type, but not the IO type.  But what if this level is just too low?  You can't just wish away the need to do effective vacuuming, you might need to buy more IO capacity.

If you populate the tables with COPY FREEZE instead of INSERT, that might make more efficient use of IO.

Comment: thanks for the tip on COPY FREEZE, I might check out using this later

Comment: The IO type datails are : Storage type
General Purpose SSD (gp3)
Storage
999 GiB
Provisioned IOPS
12000 IOPS
Storage throughput
500 MiBps 

It would be interesting to know which autovacuum settings would need to be used to prevent depleting the EBS byte balance

Comment: NB. 
Loading using COPY is done in the first stage of data transformation. In subsequent stages, the loading of the large tables after truncating them is generally done through INSERT (SELECT FROM) statements